# How do I make second submenu in this particular case?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I make second submenu under the SubMenu1?

Like this:

Main Menu (tap and collapse)

____SubMenuItem1 (tap and collapse)

__________SubMenuItem2

---

Now I have only the Main Menu and one Sub Menu only.
The routes dart file:

```
import 'file:///S:/AndroidStudioProjects/test_project/lib/menu.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font.dart';

import 'package:test_project/lib/SubMenu1.dart';


final List<dynamic> pages = [

  MenuItem(title: "info", icon: Icons.book, items: [
   SubMenuItem("SubMenu1", SubMenu1(),
        ),
  ]),

];

SubMenuItem getItemForKey(String key) {
  SubMenuItem item;
  List<dynamic> pag = List<dynamic>.from(pages);
  pag.forEach((page) {
    if (page is SubMenuItem && page.title == key) {
      item = page;
    } else if (page is MenuItem) {
      page.items.forEach((sub) {
        if (sub.title == key) item = sub;
      });
    }
  });
  return item;
}
```

and the menu page dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuItem {
  final String title;
  final List<SubMenuItem> items;
  final IconData icon;

  MenuItem(
      {Key key,
      @required this.title,
      this.items,
      this.icon = Icons.label_important});
}

class SubMenuItem {
  final String title;
  final Widget page;
  final IconData icon;
  final String path;

  SubMenuItem(this.title, this.page, {this.icon = Icons.block, this.path});
}

enum OpenMode { CODE, PREVIEW }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SubMenuItem class should have a recursive list of SubMenuItems. With this recursive structure, you will add submenuitems into your submenuitems.

```
class SubMenuItem {
  final String title;
  final Widget page;
  final IconData icon;
  final String path;
  final List<SubMenuItem> items;

  SubMenuItem(this.title, this.page, {this.icon = Icons.block, this.path, this.items});
}
```

In fact, that is more appropriate for you to define it inside of the MenuItem class. With that, you won't need any SubMenuItem class.

```
class MenuItem {
  final String title;
  final List<MenuItem> items; // Here is the recursive structure!
  final IconData icon;

  MenuItem(
      {Key key,
      @required this.title,
      this.items,
      this.icon = Icons.label_important});
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your effort. I get the error: The element type 'SubMenuItem' can't be assigned to the list type 'MenuItem'.

Answer (score 0):

use expansion title as you want main mneu=> submenu1=>submenu11.
this code will help you.

```
ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text("MAin Menu"),
                  children: [
                    ExpansionTile(
                      children: [
                        Text("Sub Menu 1"),
                      ],
                      title: Text("Sub Menu 1"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: yes but how do you open routes using this?

Comment: wrap widgets with the GestureDetector or  InkWell